# How to calculate the shortest interval, for $P ( X ≤ 1 . 645) = 0 . 95$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

The problem statement said:

> Based on the fact that $\Phi(1 . 645) = 0 . 95$ ﬁnd an interval in which $X$
>   will fall with $95\%$ probability.

Therefore:

Since $P ( X ≤ 1 . 645) = 0 . 95, ( -∞ , 1 . 645)$ is a $95\%$ conﬁdence interval for $X$

The question I have problem to understand is:

> Among all possible intervals into which $X$ falls with $95\%$ probability,
>   ﬁnd the shortest one.

**How can I compute or see which is the shortest interval?**

Thanks!

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the normal curve has a bell shape, there is more area under it near the average. It appears that we are dealing with a standard normal distribution, so you want to solve for little $x$
Using the CDF,
\begin{align*}
.95 &= P(X\leq x) -P(X\leq -x) \\
&=P(X\leq x)-[1-P(X\leq x)]\tag{1}\\
&=2P(X\leq x)-1\\
&=2\Phi(x)-1
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I recognize symmetry.

This gives
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{.95+1}{2}\implies x = \Phi^{-1}\left(0.975\right) = 1.959964$$
So the interval is $(-1.959964,1.959964)$.

---

Alternatively, using the survival gives
\begin{align*}
.95 &= P(X>-x)-P(X>x)\\
&= P(X\leq x)-[1-P(X\leq x)]\tag 2\\
&=2P(X\leq x) - 1
\end{align*}
where in $(2)$ I recognize symmetry for the value $P(X>-x)$.
This results in the same interval.

Comment: Why is this necessarily the shortest interval?

Comment: @j.d.allen It's a heuristic argument, using symmetry. If you have a more rigorous or accurate solution, please share.

Comment: @j.d $[a,b]$ is optimal only if $\phi(a)=\phi(b)$, otherwise you can move some mass from one side to another and shorten the interval. Think of it as a greedy algorithm - you start at $0$ and add (unadded) points with the highest density available - which are symmetric around 0.

Comment: As for the reason that why this is the shortest interval, one may refer to "Statistical inference" by Casella and Berger 2nd edition on page 441, Theorem9.3.2. https://fsalamri.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/casella_berger_statistical_inference1.pdf

Comment: Is there a problem in your last equation? 2P(X<X)-1 is the correct answer?

Comment: @JulietaR Sorry about that, I reversed the order somehow by mistake. I got the correct interval, and I knew it was the correct interval, that is why I must have overlooked the error. Sorry again!